# Hide Portal/Community Roles in Report Hierarchy

Tags: reporting, role-hierarchy

[image]Is it possible to not show Portal/Community Roles in Role Hierarchy when doing Show Hierarchy? I could not find any settings for this nor any confirmation that this can't be done.

Comment: Are you using a Portal or a Community? Which license? Customer Communities do not use Roles neither do most Portal licences. Partner Licenses are the only ones I'm aware of that would use a Role with the possible exception of a Community Plus license. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @crmprogdev We are using Customer Community Plus Login license.

Comment: How many different Roles do you have configured for your Community and where are they appearing?

Comment: Since each community user takes a separate role and we have lots of community users, the whole report page is taken up with Community role hierarchy. I have attached the screenshot in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, your screen capture is completely gray when I try to view it on my screen. Were it me, I'd limit the number of roles available to community users. There's no reason for each user to have a separate or unique role (that's how it sounds from your description) just as you would in a standard org.

Comment: Sorry, I had to do that because it has customer names. The point was that the grey area takes up the whole page and some more. Sorry that I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have some additional info for you that I think you may find helpful. It sounds as though you may perhaps be creating additional roles programmatically which is not a good practice. As your community grows, this will create a problem for you. From [Communities User Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_communities_users.htm&language=en_US&type=0):

> **Community License Type** ------------------ **Number of Users**
>
> Partner or Customer Community Plus ---- 1 million
>
> Some community licenses, such as Customer Community Plus and Partner Community, require roles associated with an account. Role proliferation degrades performance for your org, so make sure you don’t use more roles than necessary in your org.

From [Set Custom Community Roles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_community_role.htm&type=0):

> Community members are typically assigned the role of partner, customer, or employee. However, you can create custom roles that replace standard ones. You can also choose to display the member’s company name in place of a role.

Creating Custom Roles is what it sounds to me as though you're doing. Further:

> Creating custom role names is done simply through member administration in community management. Using a company name instead of a role is simpler yet: just turn on the **Show Company Name as Community Role** permission enabled. If the permission is off, users may see the company name elsewhere, such as on a member’s profile, but not in place of the role.

Of most important to you is [Set the Default Number of Community Roles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_default_roles.htm&type=0):

> These settings apply if your community is set up with Partner Community or Customer Community Plus user licenses. The limit is three roles; the system default is one. For example, if three partner roles are currently created when an account is enabled for your community–Executive, Manager, and User–but you need only the User role for new accounts, you can reduce the number to one role.
>
> **Note:** For better performance, we recommend setting this value to 1. You can then use Super User Access to grant specific users access to data owned by other users in their account.

In essence, a best practice would be to create no more than one user role for a Community Plus licensed community. Your code may need to query that Role each time your run your code to create new users. You could also store it either in a Custom Setting or Custom Metadata. This should also resolve your role hierarchy issue. All of this is explained in the Help documents I've linked you to.

In addition to the above, Community members can be removed from most standard reports, which may be part of what you need to do. However, what you're indicating demonstrates a larger problem exists with your community that needs addressed.

I've lost the reference to the link, but I recall reading in the Help that Community Users with Roles could either be removed from some reports or filtered out from them. Perhaps you'll be able to find it in the documentation by searching for it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. This is a very helpful article. I will have a look today in our system.